# Auto Deploy Next JS Application on CPanel

Tags: next.js, hosting, cpanel

I have researched and used Github Action for push changes when I push changes to Github. The file in Cpanel do get updated, but I need to rebuild the application to implement the changes. I am hosting Next JS using node js custom server.

Is there a way to solve the issue. Where changes pushed would trigger Build in Cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you send your project as-is and need to use `npm` commands, you could do this through SSH from GitHub Actions with a step that would look like:

```
    steps:
      - name: Build
        run: ssh $SERVER "cd /path/to/project && /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs**/bin/npm run build" || exit 1
    steps:
      - name: Start
        run: ssh $SERVER "cd /path/to/project && /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs**/bin/npm run start" || exit 1
```

where ** is replaced with the version of node that you want to use (and is installed)

Alternatively, you could build as a standalone in GitHub Actions and move the built files and start the server. In this case, you need to add `output: 'standalone'` in your `next.config.js` run `npm ci` and `npm run build` from GitHub Actions then move the files with scp and start with `ssh $SERVER "cd /path/to/project && /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs**/bin/node server.js`.

In this scenario, you need to move some files

```
public => /path/to/project/public
.next/standalone => /path/to/project/.next/standalone
.next/static => /path/to/project/.next/static
```